# How do you calculate how much faster time X is from time Y in terms of %?

Tags: performance, math, time

We're having a bit of a dispute at my office as to how this question should be interpreted.

**Time 1 = 0.6053 seconds
Time 2 = 1.3477 seconds

What percentage faster is time1 to time 2?**

I am of the believe that if you have a time of X seconds. X/2 (half as long) is 100% faster.

My solution to this problem is calculated as

(T2/T1)-1

1.3477/.6053 - 1 = 1.2265

Other people are saying that you should just look at these as numbers and calculate it like

1- (T1/T2)

1- .6053/1.3477 = .5508

(the answers above are rounded).

Comment: It depends on the perspective you're taking (which number serves as the comparison/baseline).  Jakub's answer is correct for one perspective.  If you want to know how much faster one is (% increase) you're probably looking for (T2 - T1) / T2.  Insert round numbers like 90 and 100 instead of the unround numbers to get everyone on the same page.

Comment: If you think of "faster" as implying which process' speed is greater, your formula would be correct.
If you think it is implying which process' time-span is smaller, their formula is correct.

Comment: There is a good answer here. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/716770/421410

Comment: The question is written incorrectly. You can't be more than 100% faster than something, without going into the past. +1 to the question anyway because it made me think

Comment: see my answer on the math site: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2807461/546590

Answer (score 28):

It makes it easier to use whole numbers..

Lets say X = 100 and Y = 50

You're saying "What percentage faster is time 1 to time 2?" This means, with respect from time 2, how much faster is time 1... Again, using time 2 as the reference point, how does time 1 compare.

So for this, you would use: T1 / T2 = (100 / 50) = twice as fast = 200%

In your case above, X < Y so it would be a percentage less than 100%. Roughly 44.9% faster.

Comment: It looks like it should be 55.08% faster as the OP posted.

Comment: `T1 = .6053`, `T2 = 1.3477`. `T1 is 55.08% faster than T2` means
`.6053 = (1-.5508)*1.3477`. (Here ‘faster than’ means the same as ‘smaller than’ in a size context rather than a speed one) You would've put an x for whatever you wanted to solve for.  
  
`T2 is 122.65% slower than T1` means `1.3477 = (1+x)*.6053 => x = 1.2265` as an example solving for x. (Here ‘slower than’ is similar to ‘larger than’). Think about it--T2 is more than 100% slower because even halving T2 is still larger than T1.
  The semantics can be confusing.
  
PS--`twice as fast` means `100% smaller than`

Comment: Answer from Darryl is wrong, as (0.6053/1.3477) * 100 = 44.9% does not mean it is 44.9% faster, just that the numerator is 44.9% of the denominator. so for example we can see that if time 1 was 0.2 and time 2 was 0.8, then time 1 would be 4 times faster than time 2. (not 25% faster if using the same calculation provided by Darryl).
I would also suggest looking at this:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227389/what-is-the-difference-between-faster-by-factor-and-faster-by-percent

Comment: 44.9% **slower**, right? because this is only seconds, meaning that it took longer time (T2 > T1) to do the same task.

Comment: @Jaider - You confused me for a moment but you're incorrect. If `T1=0.6sec` and `T2=1.3sec` and the question is *`"What percentage faster is Time1 to Time2?"`,* then the answer is "T1 is __% faster than T2" ... (or, you could say T2 is __% slower than T1."  ...However I have issue with the question itself.

Comment: The question (although 7yrs old) seems misleading to me, because of the statement `Using the `X/2 (half as long) is 100% faster.`.  So let's say I run two sets of code. A finishes in 1 second, B finished in 2 seconds. **#1 took half as long as #2, or, #2 took twice as long as #1.** #1 was __ faster than #2, #2 was ___% slower than #1. If

Comment: Twice as fast = 100% faster

Comment: This is quite a bad answer. A question "how much FASTER is A from B" should have a NEGATIVE result for something SLOWER. When we say "faster/slower" we are talking about SPEED (velocity), so how speed of X compared to Y is, traditionally, (Vy-Vx)/Vy. Since V=Δs/Dt we get our answer as Tx-Ty/Tx = 1.226 , or 22.6% faster, exactly as the OP suggests. With reversed numbers we get a NEGATIVE result, as it is slower, not faster.

Comment: ^ I meant 122.6% faster, as the OP suggests.