# Is 70 ms 14% or 12% faster than 80 ms?

Tags: performance, percentage

When we talk about performance, benchmarks, execution time, and we tend to say that implementation A is N percent faster/slower than implementation B, what exactly we mean?

For example implementation A took 70 milliseconds, and B took 80 milliseconds.

`80/.70-100 = 14.285714285714292`

`100-70/.80 = 12.5`

This always puzzled me, is there a standard or common approach here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's off topic

Comment: Same.  I'd vote to move it to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `80/.70-100` wh-what? this achieves the same thing in a roundabout way, but it just looks bizarre to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you calculate how much faster time X is from time Y in terms of %?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127862/how-do-you-calculate-how-much-faster-time-x-is-from-time-y-in-terms-of)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be mathematic approach. You want to calculate simple percentage (how many A can fit into B...). Example:

I have 10 bananas, you have 5. So i have 200% of your bananas, but you have only 50% of mine.

`A is 70/80 of B. So A is 12,5% faster than B.
 B is 80/70 of A. So B is ~14% slower than A.`

Answer (score 3):

With a little bit of explanation...

### A. Given

Faster Value: 70ms

Slower Value: 80ms

### B. Starting with decimal notation.

> 70ms/80ms = 0.875

### C. Convert to percentage.

> p = 0.875 * 100
>
> p = 87.5%
>
> 70ms is 87.5% of 80ms

### D. Interpretation.

> 100% represents 80ms.
>
> d = 100% - 87.5%
>
> d = 12.5%
>
> 70ms is 12.5% faster than 80ms.

### Others:

Fast calculator operation for repetitive clerical work.

> 70/80*100-100 and just mentally apply absolute value to the result.
>
> 70/80*100-100 = -12.5
>
> |-12.5| = 12.5

Comment: Never have I seen a formula like that. Are you not missing brackets? Probably some advanced maths function? Its the 70/80100-100 thats getting me. Particularly the 80100